# how to change images by using swipe in android?

Tags: android

I am using this code for showing between bunch of images.I want to show all images one by one through swipe to left or right.Can anyone help me how is it possible to make a round swipe images, it means that you be able to see the first image again after reaching the last one in the list?
and how is it possible to put arrows or part of other images in the current page just to give an ides to the user which needs to swipe to left or right for changing the current picture. 
And the last question is that how am I able to make each image clickable in order to user goes to another activity page after clicking on an image? I put the function "public void onClick(View arg0) " in the adopter to go to another activity page after clicking on the images but it does not work.
thanks for your help in advance.

```
public class DestinationActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.destination);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    DestinationAdapter adapter = new DestinationAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The adapter class :

```
 public class DestinationAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;
private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.ufficio_204,
        R.drawable.ufficio_203,
        R.drawable.ufficio_202,
        R.drawable.ufficio_201
};
DestinationAdapter(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return GalImages.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
    imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (arg0.getId() == R.id.destination) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailDestinationActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
return imageView;
}
```

}

Comment: inflate the layout and get the layout id and add the imageview to it.

Comment: Hi, Can you please show me in the code how I can do it ! because I am newer in android, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a **View Flipper,** follow this tutorial to do that

[Viee Flipper](http://javatechig.com/android/android-viewflipper-example)